# Anyone ever done a basic 'scan-animation' on an image?

Tags: android, image, animation

I am looking into having a basic red-bar scan across an image displayed on an image view a vew times, back and forth, as to make it seem like a picture is being scanned.  Has anyone ever done this, know how easy it is or could they point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Step #1: Create a PNG file (or possibly a `ShapeDrawable`) that is your scan bar, with appropriate transparency as you see fit.

Step #2: Add an `ImageView` to your `RelativeLayout` that holds the image from step #1, possibly set to have `android:visible="gone"` at the outset. Make sure the `ImageView` is a later child of the `RelativeLayout` than is your `ImageView` that you are "scanning", so it will appear to float on top.

Step #3: Use a `TranslateAnimation` to animate the `ImageView` from step #2 (after making it visible) by whatever pattern you want.

Step #4: When the animation is complete (via the `AnimationListener`), make the `ImageView` be gone again to return you to the state you were before the animation began.